# PHP replace multiples \r\n for a <br>

Tags: php, regex

I have the string:

> SOME TEXT\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\nr\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n

And i need:

```
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
```

I've try whit:

```
$adContent = str_replace("\n","<br>",$adContent);
$adContent = str_replace("\r", "<br>", $adContent);
-------
OR
$adContent = nl2br($adContent);
-------
$adContent = preg_replace("/(?:\s*<br[^>]*>\s*){3,}/s", "<br><br>", $adContent);

I think the REGEX "/(?:\s*<br[^>]*>\s*){3,}/s" not working.
```

Comment: Why don't you use [nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)?

Comment: I need 2 <br>, nl2br covert all \n and \r

Comment: Note that your sample input data appears to have some typos.  It has a stray `r` in there, without a preceding backslash.

Comment: Can you share the actual text?

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace` with the pattern `(?:\r?\n[ ]*)+`, and replace with `<br><br>\n`:

```php
$input = "SOME TEXT\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nSOME TEXT\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
$output = preg_replace("/(?:\r?\n[ ]*)+/", "<br><br>\n", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
SOME TEXT<br><br>
```

Comment: Not working https://regex101.com/r/iD2hH7/23

Comment: [Working in this actual PHP demo](https://rextester.com/OJW83197).

Comment: Yes, it is correct but I can execute correctly\ r\n\r\n\r\n... and not with spaces \r\n \r\n \r\n how i do it good?

Comment: im using laravel 8 with php 8

Comment: I have answered the question which was actually asked above.